# How to log exceptions from a model and also display an error message for the user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Given that a user wants to mark a todo item as completed:
`@user.mark_todo_item_completed "xyz"`

The following rules are enforced by the `mark_todo_item_completed` method:

1. The todo item belongs to the user
2. The todo item is not already marked completed

   etc.

Now, presume some user who does not "own" that todo item uses cURL or something to try and update that todo item.
The models' rules will catch that and throw an exception.

My question is, if I throw the exception from the model (and also log it to a log file), how do I also show an error message
to the user (say, a generic message like "Could not update the todo item")?

What is the "way" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you shouldn't raise exeption in model.
The answer:
for example in your application controller:

```
if Rails.env != 'development'
  rescue_from Acl9::AccessDenied, :with => :access_denied
end



def access_denied(exception)
    flash[:notice] = 'Access denied'
    redirect_to root_path, :message => { :notice => 'Access denied' }
  end
```